# All things working fine for 2 monthns suddenly Error #1146 appears

Tags: php, mysql, debugging, phpmyadmin

I have a database uploaded on remote server. All things were working fine but suddenly yesterday there appears a bug. Some tables were showing on left side pane of phpmyadmin but were not visible on right side.

[image: error]
<sub>(source: [purpleartsmedia.com](http://purpleartsmedia.com/images_upload/error.jpg))</sub>

When i click on any of the left table it says #1146 the table doesn't exist.

Kindly tell me what are the reasons of these bugs? How can I restore my tables because these contain important data.

Furthermore these errors appeared in more than one database. So kindly tell me the solution ASAP. Is it due to the hacker attack? I am totally blank. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Looks like your database files got corrupted. You may still be able to repair the tables. Open phpMyAdmin and check the boxes next to the tables having problems. Then click *Repair Table* at the bottom of the table list.

Comment: @AmalMurali the tables which got corrupted are not appearing on right side. How can i check the boxes? Is there any other solution?

Comment: @Programmer talk to your hosting provider about the issue and tell them to repair the tables or restore them.

Comment: Maybe your host did some maintenance or upgrades over the holiday, and broke your database. Make sure they're aware of the problem and that they may have to do a restore. Don't delay in notifying them -- hosts tend not to keep backups for more than a few days to a week.

Comment: I have same error, any resolutions